# dynamic background image with angularJS javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

i am loading some images into DOM and creathing an array to hold these images. I want to dynamically change background image of a div called wrapper from collecting image from the array. 
How to do this?

### Now I have this

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
    $rootScope.backgroundImg="url('http://abounde.com/uploads/images/office.jpg')";   
    $rootScope.loading = false;
    console.log("about page loaded");
});
```

### I want something like this

```
var images =[imageObject1, imageObject2, imageObject3];  
//imageObject are already loaded and when i 
//call them inside a html div using .html(), 
//they show as <img src="source of the image"/>

$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
    $rootScope.backgroundImg="url('images[0]')";   
    $rootScope.loading = false;
    console.log("about page loaded");
});
```

I can create object and store them in array. I just need to have a way to use thsee image in the backgroundImg variable which sets the background style of a div

Comment: if you want a background image don't use a `<img />` tag, use the div and use `ng-style` to bind the scope data to the html attribute

Comment: use `ng-src` not `src`

Comment: Use "url("+images[counter]+")"

Comment: @Daniel_L yes, I mentioned about the img tag which i found in the dom inspector. I did not use it in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ngStyle`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) :

```
<html ng-app  ng-style="htmlStyle">
    <!-- Html here -->
</html>
```

Then:

```
var images =[imageObject1, imageObject2, imageObject3];
var currenBackground = 0;
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
    var current = currenBackground++ % images.length;
    $rootScope.htmlStyle = {
       backgroundImage: "url("+ images[current].src +")"
    };   
    $rootScope.loading = false;
    console.log("about page loaded");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to put your array of images url at scope:

```
$scope.$root.images = ['imageurl', 'imageurl1', 'imageurl2'];
```

At HTML you need to put

```
ng-style="{'background-image': 'url({{ $root.images[0] }})'}
```

This will work!